# Adjacent faces are separated on the UV map

Tags: uv

I have a truncated cone, open on both sides, laced near the top, with rims/curves along the top and bottom edges:

[image]

However, whenever I unwrap the object using the cylinder method (which seems to give the best layout solution overall), several faces that are adjacent on the model appear on the other side from their counterparts on the UV map:

[image]

This happened to the faces near the marked seam, but removing the seam - having no seams at all - results in the exact same layout.
The model does not have any modifier.

**Does anyone know why this happens and how I can prevent it, or change this behaviour during unwrapping?**

---

[image]

Additional images of the model (click for larger versions):

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

Comment: Difficult to tell from your first image, but are you sure that the seam goes right to the bottom of your object? - It looks as if you may have missed one edge at the bottom. Please upload your blend file so that we can have a closer look.

Comment: @JohnEason I double-checked, and repeated the process twice, but let me get a trimmed-down version of my file ready.

Comment: Are the top and bottom of the cone open or do they have faces to close them? Because I can't see any seams there in your screenshot.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Good point: they're open, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Very odd! In fact I added another seam to the opposite side of the object and cylinder unwrapped it again to see what would happen and got even wierder results! I'm afraid I don't have any suggestions as to what's causing that one. :^(

Comment: @JohnEason Yeah, I've done the same, but with me it didn't seem to have any effect on the unwrapping process. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: I don't know what's gone wrong with your model... a very few times I've had this problem as well, somehow the order of the faces must have been changed or whatever. The only thing that works for me is what I've done with your blend: I've made a copy of the object, deleted the last three rows of faces on the bottom and recreated them with the duplicate as reference. Now it worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks, @GordonBrinkmann, I'll try that as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but **what worked for me was to not unwrap from a side view, but from the top view, presumably so that the 'direction' of the Cylinder Projection unwrapping method changes**:

In Object Mode:  <kbd>7</kbd> (for Top View) → <kbd>u</kbd> to unwrap → 'Cylinder Projection', with the following properties: Direction: ***View on Poles*** (instead of *View on Equator*), Align: *Polar ZX*.

This is the result:

[image]

(Note for clarification: the overlapping faces of the inward turning edges on both sides of the funnel were already present in the initial model (and they can be unfolded manually, if necessary) - see the question.)